# Is there a way I can add points together for the same team in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

How can I add the points together for one team?

This is what I have tried:

```
def check_league(league_points):
    league_results = []
    for teams in league_points:
    team, points = teams.strip().rsplit(' ', 1)
    print(team, points)
```

This is the list I have:

```
['Lions 1', 'Snakes 1', 'Tarantulas 3', 'FC Awesome 0', 'Lions 1', 'FC Awesome 1', 'Tarantulas 3', 'Snakes 0', 'Lions 3', 'Grouches 0']
```

Output:

```
('Lions', '1')

('Snakes', '1')

('Tarantulas', '3')

('FC Awesome', '0')

('Lions', '1')

('FC Awesome', '1')

('Tarantulas', '3')

('Snakes', '0')

('Lions', '3')
('Grouches', '0')
```

I want the output to be:

```
'Tarantulas', '6'

'Lions', '5'

'FC Awesome', '1'

'Snakes', '1'
'Grouches', '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the string into teams and points, and then create a dictionary as we go.

```
li = ['Lions 1', 'Snakes 1', 'Tarantulas 3', 'FC Awesome 0', 'Lions 1', 'FC Awesome 1', 'Tarantulas 3', 'Snakes 0', 'Lions 3', 'Grouches 0']

dct = {}
for l in li:
    #Split only on last space
    name, count = l.rsplit(' ',1)
    if name in dct:
        dct[name] += int(count)
    else:
        dct[name] = int(count)

print(dct)
#{'Lions': 5, 'Snakes': 1, 'Tarantulas': 6, 'FC Awesome': 1, 'Grouches': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.groupby` with `sorted`:

```
import itertools

func = lambda x:x[0]
sorted_l = sorted([i.rsplit(' ', 1) for i in l], key=func)
{k: sum(map(int, list(zip(*g))[1])) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_l, key=func)}
```

Output:

```
{'FC Awesome': 1, 'Grouches': 0, 'Lions': 5, 'Snakes': 1, 'Tarantulas': 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` and iterate over the `str.rsplit` of the items in the list:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> l = ['Lions 1', 'Snakes 1', 'Tarantulas 3', 'FC Awesome 0', 'Lions 1', 'FC Awesome 1', 'Tarantulas 3', 'Snakes 0', 'Lions 3', 'Grouches 0']
>>> for n, _, v in map(lambda s: s.rpartition(' '), l):
...     d[n] += int(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Lions': 5, 'Snakes': 1, 'Tarantulas': 6, 'FC Awesome': 1, 'Grouches': 0})
```

This algorithm runs in `O(n)` without the need of sorting.

Comment: Note that using `.rpartition(' ')` is an optimised version of `.rsplit(' ', 1)` so I'd personally go for that.... (it's also slightly more explicit)

Comment: @JonClements, I always forget about partition. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: Nice use of `defaultdict`. Like it more than my own answer :)

Comment: using `rpartition` throws an error: 
`for n, v in map(lambda s: s.rpartition(' '), l): ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I forgot to update the `_` in the unpacking. It works like that now

Comment: @Chris, your solution is cool, the problem is that relies in the sorting which is not very productive for large amounts of data. I used to do that kind of stuff exactly like that also because I like the functional style :D